# How did 閒 end up becoming 閑 and 間?

Tags: glyph-origin, character-variant

I can understand the link between 閒 and 間/间, being the empty spaces where moonlight or sunlight can shine through the doors --> empty space.
But how did this 閒 also end up becoming similar to 閑/闲? And how does a "moon behind the door" or "tree behind the door" correlate with the meaning of "free time"?

Comment: I removed the Simplified Chinese characters from the question - the choices for these characters being used this way isn't particular to Simplified Chinese. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65608/why-is-the-meaning-of-kanji-%e9%96%91-leisure/65610#65610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outlier**

> PY xián (or jiān, jiàn)
>
> **FORM**
> 閒 originally depicted a door (門), such that the moon (月) could be seen through a crack in the door, indicating the original meaning “crack, split.”
>
> **COMPONENTS**
> 門
> In 閒, 門 “a double-sided door; door, gate; opening” is a form component, pointing to the original meaning “crack, split.”
>
> 月
> In 閒, 月 “the moon” is a form component.
>
> **MEANINGS**
> xián
> 1 (orig.) crack, split
> 2 ○ leisure, free time
>
> jiān
> 1 → room, space (same as 間)
> 2 ⇒ duration of time
>
> jiàn
> 1 → space in between (same as 間)
> 2 ⇒ separate

The reference they give:

> p. 837
> 季旭昇，2004《說文新證》，台北：藝文印書館印行，2014年9月第二版。

It looks like the entry in Xinzheng actually begins on page 836. Here is the combined original

> [image]
> [image]

The idea of free time is another phonetic loan again. Seems a bit climatic, I know.

---

Here is p. 1043《字源》talking about 閑

> [image]

The last sentence is quite interesting.

> 如今“閒”废止不用，“閒”的空间义由“间”表示，閒的空暇义由“闲”表示。

- 閑 was originally a character that meant, "fencing around a door."
- 閒 was orignally a character that meant, "crack/split."
- 閑 was borrowed for it's sound to indicate, "free time."
- 間 has derivative meanings of "room/space" from the idea of "crack/split."

Comment: I guess the real question is: if they were both "hean" in MC when did 閑 split to ---> x- and when did 閒 split to ----> j-?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right question. 閒 was never pronounced **jiān**, *crack* (閒, Baxter–Sagart OC: **/\*N-kˤre[n]/**) was always cognate to *space* (間, **/\*kˤre[n]/**). In MC, 閒 merged with 閑 in pronunciation.